# django admin link to reverse relation object

Tags: django, django-admin

I have following model :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
    Project,
    related_name = 'invoices'          
    )
```

Assume that I have already defined the `Project` model.

Now in **Project model admin** I want to add a link which will redirect me to the `Invoice` model detail page.I have already defined admin for `Invoice` model too. Now I have written the following code in `Project` model's `admin.py` file.

```
def invoice_link(self, obj):
    link = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:invoices_invoice_change", args=[
                                    obj.invoices_set.all()[0].id])
    return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, obj.invoice.invoice_status)
invoice_link.short_description = 'Generate Invoice'
invoice_link.allow_tags = True
```

but It is raising the following error where I have used the `obj.invoices_set.all()[0].id` to get the `id` of related invoice object.

```
AttributeError at /admin/projects/project/
   'Project' object has no attribute 'invoices_set'
```

I am definitely making a mistake here,but can't figure it out. How can I get the `id` of a **reversely related object** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related name `invoice_set` will be generated incase if you don't provide any `related_name`. But in your case you are explicitly giving the `related_name`. So you just have to use `invoices` instead of `invoice_set`.